# How to get logging package to write logdebug to file

Tags: r, logging, error-handling, io

In the basic setup provided in the `logging` documentation, we instantiate logger:

```
require(logging)
basicConfig()
addHandler(writeToFile, logger="company", file="sample.log")
```

Under this setup, `logerror`, `loginfo` and `logwarn` both print to console and save to file. However, `logdebug` do neither.

How do I change this such that all four commands both print to console and save to file (saving to file being the most important).

For example:

```
#saves to file
logwarn('a',logger="company.module")
logerror('a',logger="company.module")
loginfo('a',logger="company.module")
#doesn't save to file
logdebug('a',logger="company.module")
```

Answer (score 1):

as described [here](http://logging.r-forge.r-project.org/sample_session.php):

```
require(logging)
basicConfig(level='FINEST') # level='FINEST' is missing in your code
addHandler(writeToFile, logger="company", 
           file="sample.log", level='DEBUG') # ... same as level='DEBUG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage as per [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logging/logging.pdf)

```
basicConfig(level = 10)
or
basicConfig(level = "DEBUG")
```

FYI

```
> loglevels
NOTSET   FINEST    FINER     FINE    DEBUG     INFO  WARNING     WARN    ERROR CRITICAL
0        1        4        7       10       20       30       30       40       50
FATAL
50
```